# How to use Business Calendars in IBM BPM 8.0.1.2

Tags: business-process-management, business-process

We are trying to setup a BPM Workflow involving human services(using IBM BPM 8.0.1.2).
We are able to create Routing Polices etc for each activity , but not able to figure out
how we can  include personal calendars of each user during task assignment.

**Usecase : we do not want to assign a task to a person who is on a vacation.**

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

IBM BPM does not currently have a concept of a business calendar tied to a specific user.  You can create a business calendar for calculation of due dates (e.g. this item is due in 3 business days) that can accommodate things like holidays for these calculations, but there is no built in mechanism to create a calendar and tie that to a specific user.

Now, it would be possible to create a set of services that would allow you to create per user calendars for your organization, but that feels like the wrong solution.

In general IBM BPM wants you to assign tasks to "Participant Groups" (in 8.5 this turns into "Teams") rather than to a specific user. This greatly increases your flexibility with respect to who can actually work the task over simply assigning a task to a specific person, as you can change Participant Group membership on your runtime server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, looks like there is no feature available for personal calendars.Also, you mentioned that Participant Group membership can be changed on the runtime server (process server).It is possible to integrate this with Outlook Calendar so that when a user is on vacation, the user is removed from the participant group automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know when a user is on vacation. Now this information can either come by creating custom calendar for each person but this does not look feasible good idea or Second source to get this info, can be Vacation Management System where use applies for vacation. If you do not have Vacation Management System in you organization, then this is even better - build a simple process for vacation approval and store the data for use from this process. If you have system then look for API to retrieve user's vacation details from that system.

Either way, you use this retrieved vacation info in team filter service to assign a task to only available users.